# Solution of the IVP: $\,y'=\mathrm{e}^{-y^2}-1,\, y(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Consider the initial value problem
$$ 
\frac{dy}{dx} = \mathrm{e}^{-y^2} - 1,\quad y(0)=0.
$$

The *Method of Separation of Variables* provides that:
$$
\int \frac{dy}{e^{-y^2} - 1}  = x+c.
$$
I would be thankful who somone can give me hint.

Comment: "Gate"? What does this refer to?

Comment: Gate is an exam which is conductd by IIT

Comment: It should be $\int dy/(e^{-y^2}-1)=x+c$.

Comment: @JULLIAN AGUIRRE :sorry i am editing  my problem

Comment: @user120386 *Ach so*... Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, this Initial Value Problem (IVP) can not be solved using [*Separation of Variables*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) since the initial value, $y(0)=0$, kills the *flux function*: $\,f(y)=\mathrm{e}^{-y^2}-1$ (i.e., $\,\,f(0)=0$), and hence we can not divide by $f(y)$ in order to apply Separation of Variables.

In such case we can only EVOKE UNIQUENESS!

Our IVP enjoys uniqueness (since that flux $f$ is $C^\infty$ and hence *locally* Lipschitz continuous), and therefore, any solution of this IVP, regardless how we came up to it, is THE solution $-$ For example, try for a constant one.

So, the one and only solution of this IVP is the constant one: $y(t)\equiv 0$

**Note.** I have taught ODEs several times, and I always give examples similar to the above, in order to explain that the method of Separation of Variables needs to be treated with care!

Comment: You mean $y(t)\equiv0$, don't you?

Comment: but sir initial condition is not satisfied

Comment: @user120386: Sorry, I meant $y(t)=0$, as Julian noticed!

Comment: Suggestion: avoid 0! when meaning 0 and not 1.

Comment: @Did: good advice!

Comment: I suggest the notation $y(t)\equiv 0$...!  Possibly add the word "wow".